# Display character with unicode code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use a custom font to display icons. Each icon is a character.

I can use them in UIControls by copy/pasting the character like this:

```
myLabel.text = @"";
```

Or with the unicode hexadecimal code:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\uf000"];
```

Or

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 0xf000]
```

Now I'm trying to make it more dynamic with the characters hexadecimal codes stored in a dictionary as a NSString:

```
NSString *glassIcon = [charactersList objectForKey:@"icon-glass"]; //glassIcon = f000
```

But I can't achieve to display this character in my label.

I tried

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", [subString UTF8String]];
```

or

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[subString UTF8String]];
```

But none of this work.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't find out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* Convert it to an integer. */
uint16_t code = (uint16_t)strtol(glassIcon.UTF8String, NULL, 16);

/* Convert the charcode to a string */
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c", (char)((code >> 8) & 0xff), (char)(code & 0xff)];
```

You may need to put this at the top of your file, not sure:

```
#include <string.h>
```